# Sort nested html elements using jQquery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

How can we parse and sort nested html element as shown below:

**From this:**

```
<ins> 
    <ins> 
        <ins> 
            God
        </ins>
        Bless
    </ins>
    You
</ins>
```

**To this:**

```
<ins>
    God
</ins>
<ins>
    Bless
</ins>
<ins>
    you
</ins>
```

Output in both the cases above should be:

> God Bless you

I need to do this for all `ins` tags in DOM.

Comment: seem like a job for recursive method

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

a more simplified way to do this considering you have the HTML structure provided.

```js
var itemEl = document.querySelector('ins');
var words = itemEl.innerText.split(" ");
let container = document.getElementById('container');
words.forEach((word) => { 
  let p = document.createElement('ins');
  p.innerText = word + " ";
  container.appendChild(p);
});
```

```html
<ins> 
    <ins> 
        <ins> 
            God
        </ins>
        Bless
    </ins>
    You
</ins>

<div id="container">

</div>
```

Comment: We are creating a new div element - container for output but is there any way to directly operate on actual elements. Also, what if there is another tag present inside `ins` which is not `ins` tag. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: For your first question, yes, you can just use itemEl.appendChild(p) instead of container.appendChild ... For your second question it will not matter, the code will only get the text and then wrap into a 'ins' tag.

Comment: If this question is the accepted question please mark as accept so it'll help others when they have a similar issue. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = document.getElementsByTagName("ins")[0].innerText;
//text = "God Bless You"
var result = document.createElement("div");

for (word of text.split(" ")){ // for each word in ["God", "Bless", "You"]
    var newTag = document.createElement("ins"); //recreate <ins> tag
    var newContent = document.createTextNode(word);
    newTag.appendChild(newContent); //Put the word in it
    result.appendChild(newTag);
};
console.log(result.innerHTML); //do whatever you want with result
//<ins>God</ins><ins>Bless</ins><ins>You</ins>
```

It only work if you have one word each time.

Comment: sorry too late, pretty similar to gugateider answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <script>
    function loopOver () {
      let inses = document.getElementsByTagName("ins");
      let texts = inses[0].innerText.split(' ');
      for (let i = 0, l = texts.length; i < l; i++) {
        let brandNew = document.createElement('ins');
        brandNew.appendChild(document.createTextNode(texts[i]));
        document.body.appendChild(brandNew);
      }
    }
  </script>

</head>

<body>
    <ins> 
        <ins> 
            <ins> 
                God
            </ins>
            Bless
        </ins>
        You
    </ins>

    <script>
      loopOver();
    </script>

</body>
```

As you can see this code injects the new `<ins>` directly into the body.